# How to add data while inserting or updating entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, wcf-ria-services

We're using RIA Services in our Silverlight app, and for one of our entities we want to track who creates and update them and when. For this we've added these properties:

```
public class Person
{
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

We would like to update these values in the domain service so that we don't have to do this on the client (and because entitities will also be added/updated server side(. I tried to do it by modified the domain service method like this:

```
public void InsertPerson(Person person)
{
    person.CreatedBy = GetCurrentUser();
    person.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now();

    DbEntityEntry<Person> entityEntry = this.DbContext.Entry(person);
    if ((entityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached))
    {
        entityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else
    {
        this.DbContext.Persons.Add(person);
    }
}

public void UpdatePerson(Person person)
{
    person.LastModifiedBy = GetCurrentUser();
    person.LastModifiedOn = DateTime.Now();

    DbContext.Persons.AttachAsModified(person, ChangeSet.GetOriginal(person), DbContext);
}
```

but that didn't seem to add this data at all. I then tried to do it with sql queries after inserting/updating entities with

```
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Persons SET LastModifiedById = {0}, LastModifiedOn = {1} where Id = {2}", GetCurrentUser(), DateTime.Now, person.Id);
```

which actually updates the database, but the client is not updated/notified of the changes until the entities is fetch from the database again.

Does anyone have a good idea of how to best achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes call the

```
DBContext.SaveChanges()
```

to actually commit the changes into the database

Comment: <facepalm />

Since DbContext.SaveChanges() is never run by any of the domain service methods I was sure that it would do that somewhere in the "event chain" when calling SubmitChanges() from the client and that would catch these changes. It does not, but adding this little changes fixed it. Thanks.